# How can I launch URI from external web browser in minimized mode in UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

`Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` method launches default web browser immediately.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
     new Uri(@"https://www.example.com"));
```

The code below did not change anything.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
     new Uri(@"https://www.example.com"), 
     new LauncherOptions { 
         DesiredRemainingView= Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum });
```

I want to launch URI from external web browser in minimized mode(It just tells the user in a minimized state, just in a flashing).

I want to redirect web page to external browser, but do not want to interrupt the user by opening a web page immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to do this using the `Launcher` API. You can choose the desired window size, but the result will always be a visible window.

You could do so by adding a full-trust component which would do so using the  [`ProcessWindowStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle?view=netframework-4.8) property of [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8) but this sounds like a big overkill for a small benefit.

Comment: This is a very clever way! Great.

Comment: It's impossible. UWP app can not execute or launch directly exe because UWP runs in a sandboxed environment. So UWP app can not use System.Diagnostics.Process.

Comment: Martin Zikmund's mean that you could use desktop-bridge to control win32([full-trust component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher)) app then invoke `System.Diagnostics.Process` indirectly.